# Displaying data on screen as its saved to file

Tags: java, android, file-io, text-files

How would I go about displaying, on screen, lines of data that I'm saving to file on the same click?

Here is the code I use to write to file:

```
checkIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clock_in);
        checkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            private int entryCounter = 1;

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            long startTime = b.getLong("startTime", 0);

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        vibrator.vibrate(100);  
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/timer/timer.txt", true));
            out.write(entryCounter +  "," + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "," + dateFormat2.format(new Date(elapsedTime)));
            entryCounter++;
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

So as I click it save to file and displays text on screen.

Comment: Append the text (that you are writing to a file) to a StringBuilder as well, then get the final text using StringBuilder.toString(), and display it on screen. Or is your question "how do I display text on screen"?

Comment: yeah i have a 3 line textbox i would like to display it in, but unsure of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void tee(String line, PrintWriter out, TextView v) throws IOException {
  out.println(line);
  v.append(line + "\n");
}
```